# How to force the second, third... and next rows to show Delete Button in dynamic field in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dynamic, laravel-blade

When I fetch data in from datatabse to dynamic form it shows like this. How to force the second, third... and next rows to show **DELETE** button. I want the first row only to show Add and the rest is delete. 
[image]

My blade code

```
@foreach ($form->requirements as $reqs)
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][requirement]"
                 placeholder="Enter requirements"
              value="{{ $reqs['requirement'] }}"class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="dynamic-ar"
                class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</button>
          </td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

the script

```js
var i = 0;
$("#dynamic-ar").click(function() {
  ++i;
  $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[' + i +
    '][requirement]" placeholder="Enter requirements" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-input-field">Delete</button></td></tr>'
  );
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-input-field', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable made available to you by Laravel:

```
@foreach ($form->requirements as $reqs)
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="addMoreInputFields[0][requirement]"
                 placeholder="Enter requirements"
              value="{{ $reqs['requirement'] }}"class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="dynamic-ar"
                class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</button>
          </td>
          @if (!$loop->first)
            // your delete button code here
          @endif
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```